# What's the application for using AWS presigned URL to PUT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pre-signed-url

As far as I know, presigned url is a way to grant permission for outsiders to operate through a given url, but this url seems to be really strict in terms of forming. Any difference when checking the signature can result in a `403`

For downloads, it's simple, but what about for uploads?

Let's say I want to generate a url that uploads `test.txt` to `testbucket`, I could use

```
s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='put_object', Params={'Bucket': 'testbucket', 'Key': 'test.txt'}, HttpMethod='PUT', ExpiresIn=120)
```

but doing so results in an empty file in my bucket when calling the url (`requests.put(url)`)

I have to specify the content like

```
with open(some_file, 'rb') as f:
    s3.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod='put_object', Params={'Bucket': 'testbucket', 'Key': 'test.txt', 'Body': f.read()}, HttpMethod='PUT', ExpiresIn=120)
```

In order to actually get a meaningful upload.

But does this defeat the purpose? This url is supposed to be sent to others for them to use. If I already know everything about the file, including its content, doesn't that mean I already have the file? What if it's an unknown file that I can only get some info like `file_name` and maybe `content-length` and `content-type`?

And even if, say, I create an API endpoint and ask the user to pass in the data (including its content, I guess), and then I generate the url for the user to use, I might as well get the data and upload directly instead of going through a pre-signed url, right?

And this is one single transaction. It seems like it'll get a lot more complicated when I want to do multi-part upload. Do I need to generate multiple pre-signed url's for such user? I can't find it making sense. Can someone educate me?

Comment: You don't supply the body. You supply the bucket and key, the SDK gives you a pre-signed URL, and you share that URL with your client. Your client then uploads a file to that URL. You dictate the bucket and the object key, while the client supplies the file content.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to call it from client's side? I tried forming url only with `bucket` and `key`, and when I do a `requests.put`, i kept getting 403 with `SignatureDoesNotMatch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't supply the body. You supply the bucket and key, the SDK gives you a pre-signed URL, and you share that URL with your client. Your client then uploads a file to that URL. You dictate the bucket and the object key, while the client supplies the file content.

Here's an example of how to generate a pre-signed URL for uploads:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
print s3.generate_presigned_url('put_object', { 'Bucket': 'xxx', 'Key': 'yyy' }, 3600)
```

Here's an example of how to upload to a pre-signed URL:

```
import requests

payload = 'fred'
url = <whatever previous script returned>
r = requests.put(url, data=payload)
r.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: this is beautiful. Thanks!